# Understand Heap-dump and Thread-dump for Large-scale application

Tags: java-11, heap-dump, jvisualvm, thread-dump

I go through some tutorials of Java Profilers (JVisualVM, JProfiler, YourKit) on Youtube as well as Pluralsight. I got a little bit idea regarding how to check heap-dump and how to find the memory leak. But these all tutorials are elementary.

My query is, when I analyse in heap-dump, I saw only 3 types of objects `char[], java.lang.String and java.lang.Object[]` which covers almost all memory(more than 70% always). But none from my application.
And the same way for thread dump, I saw HTTP-8080 request (the port I am using) and that leads me to `Runnable()'s run method or Java Concurrent Package` and again not to any specific code to my project.

I also discussed the problem with some of my friends and analyse their application as well (which doesn't face any issues regarding memory leak and performance), but their results are almost the same.

Would you guys help to understand how to analyse heap-dump and thread-dump in JVisualVM for the large scale application? Any video, blog, anything would be helpful.

I am using OpenJDK-11, AWS ECS-Docker and Tomcat as a web-server.

Comment: It’s normal that strings occupy a significantly portion of the heap memory. The tutorials should have shown to you, how you can identify the objects referencing these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Eclipse Memory Analyzer (https://www.eclipse.org/mat/), I used it in the past several times to successfully find memory leaks, but it takes some time to get familiar with it.

Another advise I can give you is to create benchmark tests with Apache JMeter (https://jmeter.apache.org/) or another tool that lets you reproduce the performance/memory issue and identify the execution path that cause you problems.

Be aware AWS doesn't like when someone execute performance/penetration tests against their services (https://aws.amazon.com/aup/)